# sending Json information from Servlet to Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, servlets

I want to create a web app for finding the nearest supermarkets near the place everyone is everytime.

For that reason I created a jsp page where I have a Map with the coordinates of the place I am, and  also js for displaying the information of supermarkets and the markers in a Map. In my js Im trying to get all the nearest supermarket information from a Servlet with a json form.
But when i m running this it doesn't appear something. Can you really please help me?

//Here is my js:

```
 function main1() {
 $.ajax({
    url: 'Myservlet',
    type: 'json',
    data: {
       latitude: pos[0],
       longitude: pos[1],
       map: map
     },
    success: function(data){

        drawMap(data);
        drawTable(data);
    }

});
}     

 function drawMap(data){
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].latd, data[i].longd),
        map: map
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(data[i].name, data[i].region);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
 }
```

//In my Servlet

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import package1.DB.*;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.lang.*;

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

public MyServlet(){
    super();
}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=ISO-8859-7");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(response.getWriter(), true);
        List<Markets> super_markets;

    try{

        DB db=new DB();
        super_markets=db.getNearestMarkets(request.getParameter("latitude"),request.getParameter("longitude"));

        String json = new Gson().toJson(super_markets);
        response.getWriter().write(json);

  } catch (Exception ex) {
  out.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
  out.println("</body>");
  out.println("</html>");
  }
}
}// End of class
```

Comment: I don't really know Java but your google maps JS code seems to be right. 
**Couple of things I would double check:**
1. You are receiving the right **data** in the success callback 
2. `data[i].latd` and `data[i].longd` is what you want 

_you can check values with simple console.log in your browser_

Comment: you mention JSP but there is no JSP in your question.

Comment: You are not specifying the `urlPatterns` for the url of your servlet in an annotation. Are you doing this in a web.xml file?

Comment: in my jsp a jave a script with the map and also this <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> and the import of my js script i reffered up....and also some html code for the rest of the page

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the servlet container what paths should be routed to your servlet. You can do this either with a web.xml file or with an annotation in the Servlet class. for example:

```
@WebServlet({"/Myservlet/*"})
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    ...
}
```

Note that in your javascript you are using "Myservlet" where as your class name is MyServlet. It is not necessary for the class name to be in agreement with the url you are using but it can be helpful.

Comment: its the right name MyServel both :) my fault here...I  have my servlet  in the folder WEB-INF/classes..

And out of this folder I have a folder named js where inside in this, there is an another folder named first. So in the folder named first, there is my js , path like this:

--js/first/myjav.js
Which path you think is the correct in my url inside my js? Thank you!

Comment: In your javascript ajax call you have "url: 'Myservlet'," That url needs to match the string you put in the annotation as shown in my example.